# Descriptor for reading (ioctl, fcntl)

Tags: c++, boost

```
 // Wait until data can be read without blocking.
  size_t read_some(implementation_type& impl,
      const null_buffers&, asio::error_code& ec)
  {
    // Wait for descriptor to become ready.
    descriptor_ops::poll_read(impl.descriptor_, ec);

    return 0;
  }
```

inside descriptor_ops

```
     int poll_read(int d, asio::error_code& ec)
{
  if (d == -1)
  {
    ec = asio::error::bad_descriptor;
    return -1;
  }

  pollfd fds;
  fds.fd = d;
  fds.events = POLLIN;
  fds.revents = 0;
  errno = 0;
  int result = error_wrapper(::poll(&fds, 1, -1), ec);
  if (result >= 0)
    ec = asio::error_code();
  return result;
}
```

1. `pollfd`, where's the prototype defined?
2. `::poll` referring which file's poll?
3. `ioctl` , `fcntl` work for unix and window systems?
4. `const null_buffers&`, what's usage of passing a reference to a null_buffer?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `/usr/include/poll.h`
2. The one in `poll.h`! It's a syscall.
3. No, this code is unix-specific. Windows does have `WSAIoctl`, but nothing that's exactly the same as `fcntl` (which you misspelled).
4. I don't know Boost very well. You seem to have extracted that code from the `reactive_descriptor_service` class. In general, the `read_some` method reads in data, the the `reactive_descriptor_service` looks to be an implementation of the interface that merely blocks until reading is possible, then presumably some higher caller will read and buffer the actual data. The polling calls can therefore be optimised and implemented through the generic interface, without double-buffering all the data. So, the internal class overloads the meaning the `read_some` slightly, and in this implementation, the buffers argument isn't used, so a dummy argument is passed instead.